# React JS render the element to the Dom of only one html page in my Django app

Tags: html, django, reactjs

I have a Django app with frontend in ReactJS..

In which I have two html files and one App.js with two classes..

My Issues is that React executes in the App.js only the first render line segment , and didn't render the element in the second line to the other html page?!

It only renders two elements if i have the two id`s in the same html file!
how to solve this ?!

first html page:
index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div id='app'></div>
{% endblock %}
```

second html page:
arabic_home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div id='app_arabic'></div>
{% endblock %}
```

The App.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app')); {/* it only executes the first line */}
ReactDOM.render(<App_arabic />, document.getElementById('app_arabic'));
```

Comment: Since you already have two different html files, does it work when you inline just the specific render for that page?

Comment: yes , all different cases works well ... it just gives this reaction in the case i asked about

Comment: I'm not sure of it and I'm not in a place to test currently, but the issue could be that the second line does not get executed as the first line tries to render your app in a html element that does not exist.

Comment: no.. the first line executes fine .. and when i exchange lines and the second become first .. the second get executed

Comment: When you exchange, Are you sure that `arabic_home.html` rendered?

Comment: @RajaSimon yes it works ... i have issue now with the first rendered dom to html page .. i feel like react cant render multiple elements to multiple html page in the same time

Comment: Rethink the logic please I'm not sure what you're trying so I think this logic will never work. Make the ReactDOM always render single component and do some switch statements to load the program dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

**Finally i found the solution**,

*don't know why *
but this worked fine in my case:

> by using the conditional case in App.js , i rendered the two elements conditionally and it worked well in both html pages ...

now App.jslooks like this:

```
const indexElement = document.getElementById('app');
if (indexElement) {
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, indexElement);
}

const arabic_homeElement = document.getElementById('app_arabic');
if (arabic_homeElement) {
    ReactDOM.render(<App_arabic />, arabic_homeElement);
}
```